# Removing Elements through button click within a map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm building a todo application in which all elements are inserted in a list of objects and then mapped using the map() function. I'm attempting to add a button with every map, that once clicked - will delete the specific element from the list. I've read quite a bit of documentation relating to the connection of useState and map(), but I'm still confused in how to implement this, and connect the specific element to the removal.

```
import { useState } from "react";
const List = (props) => {
  return props.items.map((item) => {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <p>{item.item}</p>
          <p>{item.date}</p>
          <p>{item.id}</p>
        </div>
        {/* Below is the button im attempting to implement */}
        <button onClick={}>Remove Item</button>
      </>
    );
  });
};
export default List;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your explanation, I kind of understand you have todo items and you need to remove an item by clicking the remove button so I have made one working demo to take dummy items and remove it, Kindly check the below code to remove items.

`list.js`

```
import React from 'react';

import { useState } from 'react';
const List = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  const [items, setItems] = useState(props.items);

  const remove = (item) => {
    console.log(item);
    let filteredArr = items.filter((el) => el.id !== item.id);
    setItems(filteredArr);
  };
  const listItems = items.map((item, i) => (
    <>
      <div>
        <p>{item.item}</p>
        <p>{item.date}</p>
        <p>{item.id}</p>
      </div>
      {/* Below is the button im attempting to implement */}
      <button onClick={() => remove(item)}>Remove Item</button>
    </>
  ));
  return <div>{listItems}</div>;
};
export default List;
```

`app.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import List from './lists.js';

export default function App() {
  const items = [
    { id: 0, item: 'item 1', date: '22/12/2021' },
    { id: 1, item: 'item 2', date: '23/12/2021' },
    { id: 2, item: 'item 3', date: '24/12/2021' },
    { id: 3, item: 'item 4', date: '25/12/2021' },
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <List items={items} />
    </>
  );
}
```

working demo link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n4z2qj?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand this is by explaining an example.

Okay, so first we declare the array with the useState hook. I added some values just for example, but they are not needed.

The function `add()` will create a new integer which will be the last integer of the array plus one, and then it will be added to the items array.

The function `remove(item)` filters the items array by receiving an item as an argument and then filtering it with the `filter()` JS method which removes all elements that do not pass the condition.

As you can see in the return Fragment the `onClick` event handler passes the item parameter and then the `remove()` function knows exactly which element to remove.

```
function List() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([0, 1, 2]);

  const add = () => {
    let newInt = items[items.length - 1] + 1;
    setItems([...items, newInt]);
  };

  const remove = (item) => {
    let filteredArr = items.filter((el) => el !== item);
    setItems(filteredArr);
  };

  return [
    <Fragment>
      <p>
        <button onClick={() => add()}>+ Add Item</button>
      </p>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <p key={index}>
            {item}
            <button onClick={() => remove(item)}>x</button>
          </p>
        );
      })}
    </Fragment>
  ];
}
```

**Note**: I assume you know that `import { useState } from "react";` and `export default List;` are needed so I did not added to the code.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is `.filter` which you can put in front of `.map`. Furthermore you need a variable to keep track of the `ids` that have been clicked/ deleted (if you don't want to actually remove them but instead just hide them).

```
const deletedItems = [1,2,3,4,5];

props.items
.filter(item => !deletedItems.includes(item.id))
.map(item => {
// ...
})
```